# Write into a big XML file with NodeJS without rewrite entirely the XML file

Tags: xml, node.js, xmldom

I am writing a web application (with NodeJS) that allows monitoring small computer/equipment (like Freebox).

To add a new equipment to monitor, you have to create it graphically in web application from a dedicated menu.

The equipment is stored in a file written in XML: XML is a mandatory format, I can't take anything else.

In the XML block representing an object 'equipment', some fields will never modify: the name, the manufacturer, the model, ...

As against, other fields are often updated (date of connection, ram info, cpu info, ...) and generate a lot of writings in the XML file.

To write to the XML file, I use the Node module 'xmldom' which requires a lock for writing and completely rewritten the file.

The level of performance is not what I wish. And more, this mode of writing is not resistant to a sudden shutdown of my server.

My question: what would be the best method and technology to solve my problem and answer the following constraint:
- Write often data without having to rewrite the entire XML file every time
- Be robust in case of crash (sudden shutdown, )